# Overwriting css for angular mat-tab

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I wanted to change mat label color for a mat-tab. css that I've added is:

```
.mat-tab-label {
  min-width: 25px !important;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

It is changing color for tab. But, it is changing color for all mat-tabs in whole application.  How can I change for a particular tab alone.

Comment: if you are setting the style for the tab in the global style.css or scss it will be change for all. You need to add a file for isolate into the component where you want to use that style.

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz you are right.

Comment: I added css to individual component. But, it is reflecting on all

Comment: Try adding to style.css it will works. @MaruthiEranki

Comment: I moved to style.css and added component as prefix to .mat-tab-label. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the component tag label,

```
 app-component-name .mat-tab-label {
    min-width: 25px !important;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Or add a class to the tab

Answer (score 1):

You have to override class style in style.css or style.scss

```
.mat-tab-label {
  min-width: 25px !important;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-active-89vnui